Pyppeteer (python) error regarding Chromium
I’m trying to run a simple code with Pyppeteer with the basic screenshot test program to test it out and I keep getting the following error shown in the attached image, which basically says it can’t download Chromium (a browser tool that they use)
The code I’m to run is the following:
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
import chromium
import ssl 

async def main():
     browser = await launch(verify=ssl.CERT_NONE)
     page = await browser.newPage()
     await page.goto('https://quotes.toscrape.com/', verify=ssl.CERT_NONE)
     await page.screenshot({'path': 'example.png'})
     await browser.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())

Thanks and would appreciate help
I already tried uninstalling and re installing Pyppeteer multiple times, installing chromium manually multiple times, changing my code, nothing works.
